# Excel 2007 Formula for True Positive

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel 2007 I want to calculate True Positive, True Negative, False Positive, False Negative results, based on some criterias. For example if two cells K10 and L10 contains the strings True and True respectively, then will display the Result "True Positive", if False and False = "True Negative" etc.
Here is the formula but it shows #VALUE .Thanks in advance for any help

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TRUE";K10&"TRUE";L10));"True Positive";"False Positive");IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FALSE";K10&"FALSE";L10));"True Negative";"False Negative")
```

Comment: By L10 i have another formula that returns TRUE or FALSE so i believe it would be like "This is true often".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 if statements in one cell which is not allowed. Also, you do not need to use `IsNumber(Search())`, you can just use `AND()` and use the equivalent operation to see if the cell equals TRUE or FALSE

To do it correctly you need nested if statements like so:

```
=IF(AND(K10=TRUE,L10=TRUE),"True Positive",IF(AND(K10=TRUE,L10=FALSE),"False Positive",IF(AND(K10=FALSE,L10=TRUE),"False Negative",IF(AND(K10=FALSE,L10=FALSE),"True Negative"))))
```

Here is the truth table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response.So is it not possible to do this only in one cell?

Comment: It would be but more info is needed. Suppose one is true and the other is false. What would the output be? False Positive or False Negative?

Comment: If we suppose one is true and the other is false the output will be False Positive.If both are True then the output will be True Positive.

Comment: So it will never be False Negative?

Comment: I have updated my original answer. Please mark it as answer if it is correct.

Comment: Slight twist on Bijan's otherwise solid answer.  Four "if()'s are not required,only three,  First and second are to establish the "true positive/negative", the third is only to determine If (K) is False, if not the remainder (L) must be the other false:  =IF(AND(K10=TRUE,L10=TRUE),"True Positive", IF(AND(K10=FALSE,L10=FALSE),"True Negative", IF(K10=FALSE,"False Negative","False Positive")))

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work fine for you:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K10,"TRUE")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(L10,"TRUE"))),"True Positive",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K10,"TRUE")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(L10,"FALSE"))),"False Positive", IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K10,"FALSE")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(L10,"FALSE"))),"True Negative", IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K10,"FALSE")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(L10,"TRUE"))),"False Negative"))))
```

Comment: You do not need IsNumber(Search()). You can just do `AND(K10=TRUE,L10=TRUE)`

Comment: Yes i realized that after posting. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

NOT the same results as the accepted answer, but based on "one is true and the other is false the output will be False Positive":

```
=CHOOSE(1+K10+L10,"True Negative","False Positive","True Positive")
```

Comment: For the same results, using CHOOSE, you could try: `=CHOOSE(BIN2DEC(N(K10)&N(L10))+1,"True Negative","False Negative","False Positive","True Positive")`

Comment: Thank you.  I might have posted as an answer, but one was already accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This formula provides the same results as Bijan's, and can be easily altered to account for any combination of TRUE FALSE depending on the results desired.

```
=CHOOSE(BIN2DEC(N(K10)&N(L10))+1,"True Negative","False Negative","False Positive","True Positive")
```

It makes use of the fact that TRUE and FALSE evaluate to One and Zero when coerced to a numeric value.

The results give an output of True ...  or False ... depending on K10; with ...positive or ...negative depending on whether L10 agrees with K10